# Implementing a simple version of find in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an assignment that requires me to create a version of `find` that can take these parameters:

1. `-name` (handling patterns for names)
2. `-type` (f and d)
3. `-print`
4. `-exec` (and being able to handle `{}`, although if `exec` is present, you can assume it will always be the last argument and need not be terminated by a semi-colon.

It also states that "The predicates can come in any order and are implicitly short circuit ANDed together. Do not handle -o (OR)." I am also not allowed to use `find` in my script.

So an example input would look like this:

```
myfind ~/dirtocheck/ -name '*.o' -type f -print -exec /bin/mv {} ~/.TRASH\;
```

I have a few questions on how to accomplish all of this.

First of all, I was wondering how to use recursion to navigate down the path. Here is sort of a pseudo code version of my function for this:

```
recurse_path () {
    for i in "$@"; do
        # call a function that executes rest of program
        if [[ -d "${i}" ]]; then
            cd "${i}"
            recurse_path $(ls ".")
        fi
    done
}
```

Second, I don't know how many arguments will be passed in or really how to parse them correctly. Is there something I should be doing before executing anything that will make this easier?

For example, I'm assuming if we have a `'-exec'` argument, I can take anything past that, and move it into an array for execution. But how would I do this?

Finally, what does it mean by "Predicates can come in any order and are implicitly short circuit ANDed together." I'm assuming this means that each thing must be true for the next one to execute, but I don't know why they would be out of order?

I would appreciate any help, or even an idea of how to structure this to get it to work.

Comment: It's hard to answer questions with more than one question in them.

Comment: There's a good chance this will be closed as "too localized" (or whatever has replaced that close reason, if that's no longer a close reason). Personally, though, I'm fine with it.

Comment: The recursion is not fine if the path given is relative. In that case, subsequent `cd "${i}"`s will likely fail because you aren't starting from the base path anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First of all, I was wondering how to use recursion to navigate down the path.

Your code is a good start. To behave like `find`, I would remove the call to `cd` and instead always use paths relative to the starting directory. That means they'll get longer the deeper the recursion goes.

Also `recurse_path $(ls ".")` is a complicated way to write `recurse_path *`.

> Second, I don't know how many arguments will be passed in or really how to parse them correctly.

As a hint, you can write a loop that examines `$1` each iteration, then uses `shift` to remove the arguments after they've been processed so `$1` points to the next set of arguments. For example, if `$1` is `-name`, process the name in `$2` and then call `shift 2`.

> For example, I'm assuming if we have a '-exec' argument, I can take anything past that, and move it into an array for execution. But how would I do this?

If you've used the `shift`-based approach then the arguments to `-exec` will naturally be accessible simply as `"$@"`.

> Finally, what does it mean by "Predicates can come in any order and are implicitly short circuit ANDed together." I'm assuming this means that each thing must be true for the next one to execute, but I don't know why they would be out of order?

You can't assume that `-name` comes before `-type`. They could be in either order, or they could be missing, or even repeated multiple times. For instance:

```
myfind ~/dirtocheck/ -name '*.o' -type f
myfind ~/dirtocheck/ -type f -name '*.o'
myfind ~/dirtocheck/ -name 'MyClass*' -name '*.java'
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help! One thing I'm realizing with the things being ANDed together, is how to process all of this? Do I process one thing (like `-type f`) search through directories that and store each file in an array, then see something else (like `-name '*.o'`) and if it a file has that extension, I store that into another array?

Comment: There are two ways. You could generate a list of all files and then filter that list one predicate at a time. Or, my preference, you could recurse over all files and every time you find a file you check it against all the predicates. That means you'd perform the `shift` loop repeatedly, once for each file. The easiest way to do that is to pass all the arguments to a helper function which does the `shift`ing. That way the `shift`s will be local to that function call and won't modify the top-level script arguments. (Functions get their own `$1`, `$2`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

First: your recursion looks basically fine. The only caveat I have is that `ls` really shouldn't be used in that manner, since it *formats* the output. You need to just use shell-glob expansion directly: `recurse_path *`. (Note that bye default this won't include anything starting with `.`. Does your assignment address how to handle "hidden" files? `find`, I think, treats them normally, which means you might have to turn on Bash's `dotglob` option.

(Note also that JohnKugelman's answer raises a good point about working on full paths. Using `cd` can still work, though--for instance, you could maintain the relative path in a variable. Though there's not really any *reason* to use `cd`.)

Second: you should almost certainly be using `shift` to get your arguments. Note that this changes your positional argument variables (`$1`, `$2`, etc) as well as your list variables (`$*` and `$@`). So, for instance, if you notice that `$1` (after some number of `shift`s) is `-exec`, then you can `shift` once more, and `$@` will contain the command to execute (modulo substituting `{}`, etc).

Third: yes, short-circuiting `and` means that if a condition is not met, then the next one is not evaluated/tested; you may find it helpful to read about short-circuiting operators, but the concept is pretty simple, and it sounds like you probably understand it already. I believe the "any order" clause means that you could, for instance, have `-type` come before `-name`.