# Calculating hash of files in directory hierarchy in Android

Tags: android, adb, md5

I need to calculate md5 hash of files in a directory hierarchy. I am using the following case as a test. The Android device I have has a `md5` binary, but needs absolute path of file (`md5 <filename>`).

I have the following directory hierarchy on a Android device:

```
/data/local/tmp/test1
/data/local/tmp/test1/test2
/data/local/tmp/test1/test2/test3
```

To get list of absolute paths, I followed the answer mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186454/28404).

```
$ adb shell 'function rcrls() { ls -d $1/* | while read f; do echo "$f"; if [ -d "$f" ]; then rcrls "$f"; fi; done } ; rcrls /data/local/tmp/' > filelist.txt
```

Now I have list of absolute paths of each file.

Next I want to read this file in a script line by line, and call `md5` for each line. `md5` will print a message if the input is a directory. I followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable/34742410#34742410).

```
#! /bin/bash
filename='filelist.txt'
cat $filename | while read LINE; do
    adb shell 'md5 $LINE'
done
```

I get the following output:

```
/data/local/tmp/test1/test2
/data/local/tmp/test1/test2/test3
could not read /data/local/tmp/test1, Is a directory
```

I expected it to print a directory warning for test1 and test2, and then md5 for test3, as test3 is a file. Can someone suggest how to fix this code ? I was expecting something like:

```
could not read /data/local/tmp/test1, Is a directory
could not read /data/local/tmp/test1/test2, Is a directory
<hash_value>   /data/local/tmp/test1/test2/test3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `find`:

```
adb shell find /data/local/tmp -type f -exec md5sum {} '\;'
```

Comment: The test device I have does not have `find` in `/system/bin` .. any other suggestion ?

Comment: Then try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711063/implementing-a-simple-version-of-find-in-a-bash-script

Comment: @Jake As you have adb access nothing prevents you from just pushing your own busybox binary to the phone. Then you have find and all the other commands available and you exactly know what parameters they support and how the output is formatted.

Comment: Thank you @DiegoTorresMilano.

Comment: Thank you @Robert.

Comment: If you are in shell (adb shell), then to get md5 of all the files in current directory:
```find . -type f -exec md5sum {} ";"```

Answer (score 2):

As alternatives to the accepted solution, hashdeep or hashdir can also be used.

for hashdeep;

```bash
apt install hashdeep # on android, termux supports apt by default 
hashdeep -rl .
```

for hashdir;

```bash
pip3 install hashdir
hashdir .
```

disclaimer: I am the developer of hashdir (https://pypi.org/project/hashdir/)